# how can I download a file using a pattern in ansible

Tags: ansible

Hi I need to fetch below file per server

- /var/adm/crash/prework-20200417-ansible/bat1-summary.log
- /var/adm/crash/prework-20200417-root/super2-summary.log
- /var/adm/crash/prework-20200417-ansible/gold3-summary.log

Here is my yml file

```
- name: Will fetch the pre_work log
      fetch:
         src: "{{ item }}"
         dest: /var/adm/crash/pre_work_log
      with_fileglob:
        - "/var/adm/crash/prework-*/*summary.log"
```

Seem the pattern is not being interpreted properly and I get below

[WARNING]: Unable to find '/var/adm/crash/prework-*' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

[WARNING]: Unable to find '/var/adm/crash/prework-*' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

[WARNING]: Unable to find '/var/adm/crash/prework-*' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

[WARNING]: Unable to find '/var/adm/crash/prework-*' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

any advice best way to fetch a file with matching pattern? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the possible way to to achive your requirement

```
  - name: find directory and log files
    find:
      paths: /var/adm/crash/
      recurse: yes
      patterns:
        - "prework-*"
        - "*summary.log"
    register: get_lists

  - fetch:
      src: "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: /var/adm/crash/pre_work_log
    with_items: "{{ get_lists.files }}"
```